# Make 24 With 7,3,7,3

Tags: mathematics

You may use math signs you wish, but you must use the numbers

> 7,3,7,3

in an equation so it equals

> 24

Is it possible? If so, show how.

**No-nos:**

- You are not allowed to combine numbers to make bigger numbers (*e.g.* you can't have 73)
- You cannot use numbers more than once, you only have **2 7s** and **2 3s**
- You have to use all the numbers given to you.

**What is a math sign? Examples: +, -, *, /, (, )**

Comment: Do I have to use both numbers exactly twice, or what?

Comment: @No. 7892142 As expected, yes.

Comment: Should you just add characters only to the left of the equals sign?

Comment: Why are there so many down votes? I mean, I also see this question as a ridiculously simple no-effort quiz, but it's not often too see such a low-scored question recently. (I'm not down voting btw)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> (3/7+3)*7 =24
>   => (3/7 + 21/7) * 7 =24
>   => (24/7) * 7 =24
>   => 24=24

Took me a while!

Answer (score 5):

**Answer**

> $$((7/7)+3)*(3!) = 4*(3!) = 24 $$

Answer (score 3):

There's an implied $1$, but I didn't actually write it:

> $7 \times 3 + 3 + \int_{\{7\}}dx$

And here's another solution (I think you can argue that $7$ is used twice):

> $7 \times 3 - 3 = 24$ in base $7$

Comment: I love the second one!

Comment: I love the second one!

Answer (score 2):

Using not all of them:

> 3*7 + 3 = 24

Using all of them:

> $\lceil 7/3 \rceil + 3*7 = 24$

Comment: "math signs" who said you could use ceil?

Comment: Also I told you in the comments you must use them all.

Comment: Who said I couldn't? "Math sign" isn't exactly a rigorous definition.

Comment: The question didn't give you permission to use that, it gives you math signs (+, -, /, *, (, ))

Comment: Added into question then :P

Comment: @warspyking "Examples" still does not exclude ceil().

Comment: Changing the rules to disallow an answer after it's posted _sucks_, @warspyking; it's incredibly frustrating for someone who's trying to participate in your challenge. Futhermore, the ceiling operation _does have_ what you call a "math sign": $\lceil x \rceil$. _Please_ please review your challenges **before** you post them and deal with things like this then, rather than snubbing your answerers.

Comment: @Josh Caswell He simply didn't understand the rules, I was trying to make it clearer for him.

Comment: "Math signs" has no standard definition, @warspyking -- there's nothing to be "not understood". It's up to you to make the rules clear _before_ posting. And, as I showed you, $\lceil\rceil$ **is** a "math sign".

Comment: @JoshCaswell And one could very well define a "math sign" for most operations anyway. If you want to be silly, you could define ~x~ = 24 for any term x.

Comment: The second answer here is clearly correct.  "Math signs" and a list of examples is NOT a definition.  It's ridiculous to expect that ⌈ ⌉ might be excluded.

Answer (score 1):

> <s>((7*7)^{1/2})*3+3</s>
> $\sqrt{7*7}*3+3$
> $=(7)*3+3$
> $=21+3$
> $=24$
>
>  (equivalent to original answer but w/o using "1/2")
>  Of course it's unclear if a radical is covered by "math signs" ...

Answer (score 0):

> square root of 7*7 with is 7 * by 3 + 3

Comment: Hi archie, Welcome to Puzzling SE. Please ensure that your answers make sense to immediate readers, and hide your answers using the spoiler tag >!    Alsoif a question already has an accepted answer, be sure your answer adds something good to the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

I guess square root and factorial are allowed:

> $$(\sqrt{7-3} +\sqrt{7-3})! = (2+2)! = 4$$

Comment: You need to edit the right-hand side to be 24, not 4.